# Bar chart with several non mutually exclusive characteristics

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data set with a variable that has several other characteristics, which are not mutually exclusive. Here's the data.

```
df <- structure(list(cont1 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Africa", "Asia", "Europe", "LAC"), class = "factor"), SIDS = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("No", "SIDS"), class = "factor"), LDC = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("LDC", "No"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("cont1",
"SIDS", "LDC"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -17L))
```

So when I put it into long format `df.m <- melt(df, id.vars = c("cont1"))` I can build the plot with `ggplot2` but get all the NAs in the plot. If I exclude them the proportions are distorted because there are more NAs in one of the categories.

```
ggplot(df.m, aes(x = cont1, fill = value)) + geom_bar()
ggplot(df.m[df.m$value != "No",], aes(x = cont1, fill = value)) + geom_bar()
```

Is there a way to have a bar plot of the variable `cont1` with the `value` as a fill without the NAs distorting the proportion? That is can I use a different length for the fill in `ggplot2`?

Comment: I can't see where is the problem. In your example data.frame there is no NAs. For is anwser "No" your NAs?

Comment: Yeah that was a confusion from my side. I mean "No".

Comment: You can edit your questions to change that mistake.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking: "without the NAs distorting the proportion?" What value do you want to be displayed? "That is can I use a different length for the fill in ggplot2?" You can pre-summarize the data and assign the height to the `y` aesthetics (and set `stat="identity"`), but I'm not sure what you want the height to be.